# Unable to show 2nd UIViewController from 1st within navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a Main storyboard, which has below setup

--Navigation Controller (is initial View Controller)

----Table View Controller (root view controller) - #1

----UI View Controller (segue type is Modal coming from Nav.Ctrl) - #2

#1 connected to custom class

#2 connected to different custom class

Inside #1, when a button clicked from one of the table cell.. I wanted to invoke #2 to get something done and wanted to come back (via Back button click) to #1

I have tried few different codes, no luck!

Below code produces black screen but Navbar info contains option to go back to main page

```
vcControl2 *popup = [[vcControl2 alloc] init];
popup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.viewController.navigationController pushViewController:popup animated:YES];
```

Below code produces black screen with blank Navbar info

```
vcControl2 *vc = [[vcControl2 alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil ] ;
UINavigationController * navcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.viewController presentModalViewController: navcontroller animated: YES];
```

Below code produces black screen with NO Navbar info

```
vcControl2 *popup = [[vcControl2 alloc] init];
popup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:popup animated:YES];
```

Any thoughts?

---

I have solved it with below approach, presenting it here for future users.

On storyboard, selected Prototype cell that is available inside Table View Controller (root view controller) - #1

Clicked and created a "storyboard segue" with style "Push" and called it as "Detail"

Inside my code, I have got below and successfully invoking #2 (UIVwCtrl)

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail" sender:self];
```

Comment: So what is the problem ? you can not present the viewController modally ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `Storyboard` you should use a **`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`** method to load a view controller:

```
YourViewControllerClass *popup = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourPopupViewControllerID"];
popup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:popup animated:YES];
```

Note that method:

```
+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil
```

takes storyboard name **without** the filename extension.

Comment: Thanks reecon. No luck. Getting an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle" for code --- vcControl2 *popup = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil]
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Control2"];

Comment: Instead of providing @"Main.storyboard", call the method with @"Main" as a storyboard name.